# I heard that Haskell variables are immutable but i am able to reassign and update variable values

Tags: variables, haskell, immutability, mutable

I heard that Haskell variables are immutable but i am able to reassign and update variable values

[image: Reassigning variables]

Comment: No you are not: you introduce a new variable with the same name in a tighter scope. That is something different, since you can (well not really in ghci directly, since here you basically construct a monad online), construct a monad that escapes this scope, and then it will take the outher variable back as value.

Comment: ok thank you Willem Van Onsem

Comment: Please don't post text, such as console output, as images  -- just copy and paste the text directly. It is easier for everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that GHCi syntax is not quite the same as Haskell source-file syntax. In particular, `x = 3` actually used to be illegal as such:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> x = 3

<interactive>:2:3: parse error on input ‘=’
```

Newer versions have made this possible by simply rewriting any such expression to `let x = 3`, which has always been ok:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let x = 3
Prelude> x
3
```

By contrast, in a Haskell source file, `let x = 3` has never been legal by itself. This only works in a particular environment, namely a *monadic `do` block*.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   let x = 3
   print x
```

```
3
```

And the GHCi prompt by design actually works like the lines in a `do` block, so let's in the following discuss that. Note that I can also write

```
main = do
   let x = 1
   let x = 3
   print x
```

```
3
```

And that's basically what's also going on in your GHCi session. However, as the others have remarked, this is *not* mutation but *shadowing*. To understand how this works, note that the above is essentially a shorthand way of writing

```
main =
   let x = 1
   in let x = 3
      in print x
```

So, you have *two nested scopes*. When you look up a variable in some expression, Haskell always picks the “nearest one”, i.e. in the inner scope:

```
main =
   let x = 1
     ┌──
   in│let x = 3
     │in print x
     └─
```

The outer `x` isn't touched at all, it's basically unrelated to anything going on in the inner scope. The compiler will actually warn you about this, if asked if there's anything fishy in your file:

```
$ ghc -Wall wtmpf-file16485.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( wtmpf-file16485.hs, wtmpf-file16485.o )

wtmpf-file16485.hs:3:8: warning: [-Wunused-local-binds]
    Defined but not used: ‘x’
  |
3 |    let x = 1
  |        ^

wtmpf-file16485.hs:3:12: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraint to type ‘Integer’
        Num p0 arising from the literal ‘3’
    • In the expression: 3
      In an equation for ‘x’: x = 3
      In the expression:
        do let x = 1
           let x = 3
           print x
  |
3 |    let x = 1
  |            ^

wtmpf-file16485.hs:4:8: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘x’ shadows the existing binding
      bound at wtmpf-file16485.hs:3:8
  |
4 |    let x = 3
  |        ^
```

There: the second definition simply introduces a *new*, more local variable which also happens to be called `x`, but is unrelated to the outer variable. I.e. we might as well rename them:

```
main = do
   let xOuter = 1
   let xInner = 3
   print xInner
```

A consequence of all this is that a variable that's “mutated” in this way has no influence on other functions which use the original variable. Example:

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghci
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sagemuej/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> let x = 1
Prelude> let info = putStrLn ("x is ="++show x++" right now")
Prelude> x = 3
Prelude> info
x is =1 right now
```

Another consequence is that “updates” which try to use the old value behave in a funny way:

```
Prelude> let s = "World"
Prelude> s = "Hello"++s
Prelude> s
"HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHell^C
```

Here, the new binding does *not* just prepend `"Hello"` to the old `s="World"`. Instead, it prepends `"Hello"` to *its own result value*, which is in turn defined by `"Hello"` prepended to... and so on, recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You're shadowing, not mutating.

Comment: Although that is strictly speaking correct, I think you should extend this answer, and give a more rigorous explanation what is happening here.